# Changing default values of variables of dll and sending them to com component

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll, com, typelib

I've written an app in C# that searches through a database and finds values that I would like to pass to another app written in a different programming language which doesn't "speak" with .NET so I need a wrapper in C++.
I've written a class library in C# that is supposed to pass values to COM component I also have written in Visual C++ and then pass them to the said language. The connection works fine. I can read those values in the different language. In Visual C++ project I'm importing a tlb file generated from .NET class library.
**The problem is those values are default values of the dll I've created in C# and I want them to be values passed from the external app.**
The question is: is this even possible to achieve and if it is then how can it be done. Unfortunately my knowledge about passing values from and to C#/C++ is poor, so I don't have any idea how to solve this problem.

Here is part of the code for C# dll:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DotNetDLL
{
    public interface DotNetDLLInterface
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        string SendString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string strFromCPP);
    }

    public class MyClass : DotNetDLLInterface
    {
        public string value { get; set; }

        public MyClass()
        {
            value = "";
        }

        public string SendString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string strFromCPP)
        {
            return strFromCPP + value;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change value of the string named value for the value in another app. So does anyone know is it possible?

Comment: This is possible, but we would need to see how your code is currently structured to marshall the parameters.

Comment: Cut out the middle-man, you don't need that C++ wrapper.  Writing COM servers in C# is very simple with the [ComVisible(true)] attribute.